# I use the SELECT query to download contacts from Salesforce.com. As it is given below and i am getting "MALFORMED_QUERY" exception

Tags: salesforce, soql, force.com

I use this select query and i am not getting what's the wrong with this.

Select Id,Contact.FirstName,Contact.LastName,Contact.Title,Contact.Department,Contact.Birthdate,
   Contact.Phone,Contact.HomePhone,Contact.MobilePhone,Contact.OtherPhone,Contact.Fax,Contact.Email,Contact.MailingStreet,
       Contact.MailingCity,Contact.MailingState,Contact.MailingCountry,Contact.MailingPostalCode,Contact.OtherStreet,
   Contact.OtherCity,Contact.OtherState,Contact.OtherCountry,Contact.OtherPostalCode,Contact.Description,Contact.Account.Name From Contact where strcmp('%@',Id) = -1",lastcontactId

Comment: this doesn't seem to be an iPhone Question and i think you need to reformat it. Please Retag it!

Comment: Retagged, this is not a direct iOS question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to generate a query that uses =, e.g.

```
select name from contact where id='005123123123123123'
```

so, you can use this to generate the query.

```
NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select name,etc from contact where id='%@'", lastContactId];
```

Here's the [SOQL docs](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/sforce_api_calls_soql.htm) which has more examples.

And if you're trying to do paging, you should just run the entire query and use query/queryMore to page through the results.